# EF Lazy-Loading: Add item to navigation property without loading it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Suppose the following data model:

```
class Garden
{
    int ID;
    ICollection<Tree> Trees;
    string Address;
}
class Tree
{
    public int ID;
    public float Size;
}
```

Let's plant some trees:

```
var gardens = dbContext.Gardens.Take(10).ToList();
foreach (var g in gardens)
    g.Trees.Add(new Tree());
```

But now, each reference to `g.Trees` triggers a database query, because of lazy-loading. I could do `.Include(garden => garden.Trees)` when fetching the gardens, but then I'm transferring all the existing trees.

I could create a GardenID column in Tree, and then just add the Tree to my DbContext without touching the navigation property. But now I need to pass my DbContext around.

How can I add the tree to the garden without triggering a lazy-load of the navigation property, and without transferring unneeded data?

Comment: Either make `Trees` property non virtual, or turn `dbContext` lazy loading off.

Comment: Do you have navigation to Garden in the `Tree` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DB first then you only option is to turn off the lazy loading for the whole context.
`ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`

If using Code First then make sure mark your `ICollection<Tree> Trees` is not `virtual` which then disables lazy loading just for this collection.